# Simple WCF service with REST - Resource cannot be found - error with ASP.NET Debug Server?

Tags: wcf, rest, visual-studio-2010

I'm testing a very simple WCF-Service with REST functionality enabled.
It works fine on IIS, but the VS2010 debug webserver always says "The resource cannot be found" when appending the parameter after the .svc file in the browser uri.
Is this a known issue with the asp.net debug webserver that it cannot work with REST or am I doing anything wrong? (again: with IIS, it works)

Comment: i am having the same issue, let me know if you able to fix this issue.